# Can you attach a drawer to another application in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface

Is there a way for one Cocoa application to attach drawer-like windows to another application?  We might for example want a terminal drawer that followed around a particular Finder window.

There is a program called DTerm that opens little transparent windows over Finder windows, but one might prefer persistence.

Comment: I don't have time to work up an official answer for you just yet, but the place I'd likely start is looking up how to do Code Injection (as [described on this site](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-30-code-injection.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to checkout [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php). It allows you to write nifty bundles that are loaded into the application your targeting. If you go along with it I'd reccomend using [class dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) to gather more information on the application your working with (although Im not sure it would work with Finder)